# Ajax never initiating success: when using xhrFields

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having trouble getting the `success` call to fire in my ajax request. I know the communication is working fine, but the last call in my `PHP` script, which is a `return json_encode($array);` will fire as if it is a part of the onprogress object. I would like to "break" the onprogress call and run the success function on the last data sent via `return json_encode` when the PHP script has terminated...

Here is my AJAX call:

```
$( document ).ready(function(e) {
    var jsonResponse = '', lastResponseLen = false;   
    $("#btn_search").click(function(e){
      var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
      var lastname = document.getElementById('lastname').value;
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'search.php',
          data: $('#search_fields').serialize(),
          dataType: "json",
          xhrFields: {
                onprogress: function(e) {
                    var thisResponse, response = e.currentTarget.response;
                    if(lastResponseLen === false) {
                        thisResponse = response;
                        lastResponseLen = response.length;
                    } else {
                        thisResponse = response.substring(lastResponseLen);
                        lastResponseLen = response.length;
                    }

                    jsonResponse = JSON.parse(thisResponse);
                    document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = 'Progress: '+jsonResponse.msg;
                }
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('done!');
                document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = 'Complete!';
                document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = data;
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

And here is the basic PHP server script:

```
<?php
function progress_msg($progress, $message){
  echo json_encode(array('progress' => $progress, 'msg' => $message));
  flush();
  ob_flush();
}
$array = array('msg' => 'hello world');
$count = 0;
while($count < 100){
     progress_message($count, "working....");
     $count += 10;
     sleep(2);
}
return json_encode($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made your code work, there were 2 errors. First, in your while loop, your function name is incorrect, try this:

```
progress_msg($count, "working... ." . $count . "%");
```

Secondly, the very last line outputs nothing, so technically you don't get a "successful" json return. Change the last line of your server script from:

```
return json_encode($array);
```

to:

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

---

**UPDATE:** Full working code with hacky solution:

Ajax:

```
$( document ).ready(function(e) {
    var jsonResponse = '', lastResponseLen = false;   
    $("#btn_search").click(function(e){
      var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
      var lastname = document.getElementById('lastname').value;
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'search.php',
          data: $('#search_fields').serialize(),
          xhrFields: {
                onprogress: function(e) {
                    var thisResponse, response = e.currentTarget.response;
                    if(lastResponseLen === false) {
                        thisResponse = response;
                        lastResponseLen = response.length;
                    } else {
                        thisResponse = response.substring(lastResponseLen);
                        lastResponseLen = response.length;
                    }

                    jsonResponse = JSON.parse(thisResponse);
                    document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = 'Progress: '+jsonResponse.msg;
                }
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('done!');
                dataObjects = data.split("{");
                finalResult = "{" + dataObjects[dataObjects.length - 1];
                jsonResponse = JSON.parse(finalResult);
                document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = 'Complete!';
                document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = jsonResponse.msg;
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Search.php:

```
<?php
function progress_msg($progress, $message){
  echo json_encode(array('progress' => $progress, 'msg' => $message));
  flush();
  ob_flush();
}
$array = array('msg' => 'hello world');
$count = 0;
while($count <= 100){
     progress_msg($count, "working... " . $count . "%");
     $count += 10;
     sleep(1);
}
ob_flush();
flush();
ob_end_clean();
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

The problem with the "success" method of the ajax call was that it couldn't interpret the returning data as JSON, since the full return was:

```
{"progress":0,"msg":"working... 0%"}{"progress":10,"msg":"working... 10%"}{"progress":20,"msg":"working... 20%"}{"progress":30,"msg":"working... 30%"}{"progress":40,"msg":"working... 40%"}{"progress":50,"msg":"working... 50%"}{"progress":60,"msg":"working... 60%"}{"progress":70,"msg":"working... 70%"}{"progress":80,"msg":"working... 80%"}{"progress":90,"msg":"working... 90%"}{"progress":100,"msg":"working... 100%"}{"msg":"hello world"}
```

Which is not a valid JSON object, but multipje JSON objects one after another.

I tried removing all previous output with `ob_end_clean();` , but for some reason I can't figure out, it didn't work on my setup. So instead, the hacky solution I came up with was to not treat the return as JSON (by removing the `dataType` parameter from the AJAX call), and simply split out the final Json element with string operations...

There has got to be a simpler solution to this, but without the use of a third party jQuery library for XHR and Ajax, I couldn't find any.

Comment: Still doesn't work .... I think my issue has something to do with speed (i.e. too fast) since my last `ob_flush` is truncating the last two json arrays together and I am getting an error when `JSON.parse` initiates since there is no comma between them...

I also still do not get my success firing...

Comment: Whoops, I rechecked and I've left out one other change I did when I tried debugging your code: I removed dataType: "json" - from the AJAX call, in order to see the full result. But now it doesn't display the final message properly... I'll recheck and update my answer soon.

Comment: The problem is that the success is technically not a valid JSON array, since it's all previous progress JSONs one after another. I'm trying to erase them with something like ob_end_clean(), but it doesn't seem to work so far. I'll give you a shout if it does.

Comment: Thanks! I solved in a different route (with delays and and a condition...), but I test yours and it works so I will accept it. I think I might need to revert from ajax, unless you know a third party jQuery library to make this work...?

Comment: I was glad to experiment with it, because I use ajax/json all the time, but I've never used this onprogress method before. It looks like it's not a third party tool,  but the standard javascript XMLHttpRequest object that I've seen to pop up in a lot of other threads. I'm still unsure though on why it didn't simply work with ob_end_clean(); - according to all sources, it should erase all previous output, and then echo just one simple json object with the final results, which would be a perfect and elegant way to work with the success function. I'm tempted to make a seperate question about it.